# Initialize dictionary with tuple of parsed data

Tags: python, class, dictionary

I'm parsing a file with Register description information and trying to build a tool around these register descriptions and bit fields for reading/writing to registers on this device.  I had a text file that looked like such (There are thousands of entries/registers for this file/device):

```
# Note 'Register> 0xXX' - Register Offset Address
Register> 0x00=Configuration ID
15:0=Vendor ID
31:16=Device ID

Register> 0x04=Class Code and Revision ID
0=TMODE
7:1=Revision ID
15:8=Register-Level Programming Interface
23:16=Sub-Class code
32:24=Base Class Code

Register> 0x08 ....
...
```

I have parsed this file into a data structure that holds the register address (ex. '0x00'), register description (ex. 'Configuration ID'), the bit fields (ex. '15:0') and their descriptions (ex. 'Vendor ID').

I'm building a tool that requires access to this information based on the register address so I'm thinking of printing all of these register descriptions into a header file to initialize a dictionary like such.

```
regDict={}
regBitFieldList=[]
regBitFieldList.append( ('15:0','Vendor ID') )
regBitFieldList.append( ('31:16','Device ID') )
# ex regDict[0x00]=('Configuration ID', [('15:0','Vendor ID'), ('31:16','Device ID')])
regDict[regOffsetAddress]=(regDescription, regBitFieldList)

regBitFieldList=[]
regBitFieldList.append( NEXT REG INFO)
regDict[nextRegAddress]= (nextRegDesc, regBitFieldList)
....
...
```

I have a class that represents the device so I can readRegister, writeRegister through this class and I'm wondering *do I initialize this dictionary in another file and import the data to a class_global variable?* (see variable 'myDeviceDictionary' in example below).

i.e.

```
Class myDevice():
    myDeviceDictionary = {}  ## Import dictionary initialization to this variable?
    __init__(self):
        initialize stuff.
    writeRegister(regAddress, byteString_4):
        Write 32-bits to a register at regAdress from thisDevice
    readRegister(regAddress):
        Read 32-bits from a register at regAddress from thisDevice
```

Comment: If your collection of data is large and complex, you should also consider using a SQL database or similar. I might save you headache in the long run.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're initializing the class with the contents of the header file, I would recommend doing the init of the dictionary inside of the constructor (**__init__**). If you want to support different header files, then have the constructor take an argument that's the path pointing to the header file you want to read in.

Having that dictionary be class-level is fine -- it's a member of the class.

**Edit with response to OP's comment:**

To initialize the dictionary using this method from another file, you would first `import` the class and then instantiate it from the other file.

i.e., assuming the other file is in the same directory as **myDevice.py**, you could do something like this:

```
import myDevice

device = myDevice('/home/user/foo.header')
```

And then the constructor you defined within the class would read in the specified header.

Comment: How do I reference it from the other file?

Comment: I'm not sure I follow what you're asking. Do you mean how do you reference an instance of the class in another file?

Comment: I want to initialize this dictionary inside my constructor from another file.